# How to install 2 different magento2 instance with same server and same database

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, installation

I want to install 2 magento2.4.4 on my server and connect with single database .

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you would not make use of the Magento multi-store functionality? Two applications passing data to the same database at once seems to be a bad idea, in my opinion.

Multi-store allows for multiple URLs, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't see the benefit of using the same database for 2 instances; it will just lead to performance issues, and complicate work for developers.

Also, I guess many extensions will have problems with this setup.

However, to answer the question:
At least one of the instances needs to have a `db->table_prefix` set in `app/etc/env.php`; you need to set this value before installation.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

It's Overlapping your both site, it's not possible to 2 site in 1 database, both data overlapping every update, so i'm not prefer to you.
But you can do it with **app/etc/env.php** in give databse name for both site.